# Unexpected behaviour parsing integer to string

Tags: python

While trying to solve a [checkio](https://py.checkio.org) exercise I stumbled into a strange behaviour.

```
def friendly_number(number, base=1000, decimals=0, suffix='',
            powers=['', 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y']):
    power_i = 0    
    while abs(number) >= base and power_i < len(powers)-1:
        number /= base
        power_i += 1

    number_str = str(number)

    return number_str

fn = friendly_number(10**32)
```

I was expecting `fn == "100000000"`, but I got `fn = "99999999.99999999"`. I narrowed it down to the step `number_str = str(number)`. The strangest bit was testing this on the command line: when I did that the value returned was `"100000000"`. What is happening here?

Comment: From your output and your expect output I suspect you might be running into a [floating number problem](http://floating-point-gui.de/).

Comment: You need to use `//=` with double slashes. This tells Python you want to round the result of the division to the nearest whole number=.

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar It would seem like it, but since I'm not using floats anywhere i can't understand how could that be.

Comment: @padrezulmiro as Christian said, using `/` for division returns the result in float, even though dividing ints by ints.

Comment: @ChristianDean Why? I checked the value of number after the division loop, its the expected value of `100000000`.

Comment: @padrezulmiro What do you mean. Did using `//=` solve your problem? Or are you asking _how_ `\\=` solved your problem?

Comment: @padrezulmiro, instead of `print`ing out the value after the loop, check its `type()`.  Then consider "[What every computer scientist should know about floating point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)."

Comment: @ChristianDean It did solve my issue. But like I said, the value being parsed into a string, which is a float as @ViniciusAguiar pointed, is the expected `100000000`. So being a float also causes some shenanigans on the conversion to string?

Comment: @padrezulmiro No. Your problem is that `/=` returned a floating-point number. You then converted that number to a string and returned it. That's it. Python had no problem converting the float into a string.

Comment: @ChristianDean But if the conversion is not the problem, wouldn't the result of the several _floating-point_ divisions have to already be something like the unexpected value `99999999.99999999`? Although, I was checking on the value `number` through the loop - it did deviate on some steps. Yet the final aproximation is also the correct one: `100000000`. This is what bugs me. Dunno if it could be something on the __str__ method of float

Comment: @ChristianDean Also, `isinstance(number, int) == True` after the floating-point division

Comment: @padrezulmiro _"Yet the final approximation is also the correct one: 100000000"_ - What do you mean by that? When I use `/=` in the loop, `number` is  a float. What exactly do you mean when you say "approximation"? Also, if you use `/=` in the loop, `isinstance(number, int)` will be `False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3 there are two types of division, ***floating-point*** and ***true division***. floating-point division will yield a float, while true division will round the float to the nearest whole number and return an integer:

```
>>> 1 / 1 # floating-point division
1.0
>>> 1 // 1 # true division
1
>>>
```

In your case, you're using the in-place floating point division operator, `/=`. You need to use the in-place *true division* operator:

```
number //= base
```

With the change above the value of `fn` is the expected result, `100000000`:

```
>>> fn = friendly_number(10**32)
>>> fn
'100000000'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 use:

```
number //= base
```

Your current statement (`number /= base`) should work fine in Python 2.